# Maven2 unpack include only internal files

Tags: maven-2, maven, include, unpack

I have the next artifact item for maven unpack

```
<artifactItem>
    <groupId>blabla</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo-bar</artifactId>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/outer-resources/META-INF/wsdl/</outputDirectory>
    <includes>xsd/*</includes>
</artifactItem>
```

I need to copy ONLY files and subfolders from xsd, but not xsd folder. How can I use includes/excludes to make this?

Comment: Can you give a little bit more of your pom? Do you use the maven-dependency-plugin ?

Comment: Yes, I use it. What exactly do you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you may not be able to do this by using maven dependency plugin alone.

But you can try using a combination of maven dependency plugin and [maven resource plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) to achieve this.  You can use maven dependency plugin to unpack the contents of the dependency to a specific directory and then use maven resource plugin to copy the desired contents from there to another location, excluding the parent xsd folder.

You would need to ensure that both the plugins are invoked in the same phase and goal in the correct sequence.